# How can I squeeze video of certain length into smaller length

Tags: video, video-editor, conversion

For example how to turn 1:03 video into 1:00 without cutting anything. Can I do it on any mobile video editor?

Comment: So, you want to speed it up?

Answer (score 1):

This is generally done by retiming the video. Usually, if you're retiming by anything other than double or half, you need to use a professional application such as Final Cut Pro X or Premiere. They will have options for doing the speeding up in a number of different ways such as "Frame Blending" or using "Optical Flow".

For mobile, a quick search with these terms ["app to speed up video iPhone"](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=app+to+speed+up+video+iphone&t=osx&ia=web) shows a number of results.